# Customized Comment Form Issues

Tags: customization, comments, comment-form

I'm developing a Wordpress theme and I faced a problem while customizing a comment form.
What I wanted is to eliminate URL field and put my own classes for name and email fields. I'm doing it like this:

```
    $commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();
    $req = get_option( 'require_name_email' );
    $aria_req = ( $req ? " aria-required='true'" : '' );
    $fields =  array(
        'author' => '<p class="post-comment-name"><label for="post-comment-name">' . __( 'Name' ) . '</label><input type="text" id="post-comment-name" name="post-comment-name" placeholder="Write your name" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" ' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',
        'email' => '<p class="post-comment-email"><label for="post-comment-email">' . __( 'Email' ) . '</label><input type="text" id="post-comment-email" name="post-comment-email" placeholder="Your email to reply" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_email'] ) . '" ' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',
        'url' => ''
    );
    $comments_args = array(
        'title_reply' => '',
        'comment_notes_before' => '',
        'id_submit' => 'post-comment-submit',
        'fields' =>  $fields
    );

    comment_form($comments_args);
```

After all visually I've got what I wanted. I've got form with all the styles I wanted and with no URL field whatsoever.

**The problem** is when I try to submit the comment form with all the data filled in I get the message: "Fields name and email are required" and comment submission fails.

Tried almost everything, nothing helped.
Please assist!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work.

All you need to do is to preserve **id** attributes for all the fields when you try to customize them:

```
$fields =  array(
    'author' => '<input id="my-input-id" />', // Does not work
    'email' => '<input id="email" />', // Works
);
```

All you need to do to make it work is to preserve the input **id**. I don't know maybe there's a way to somehow make WP process comment forms with different input **ids**, but I failed to find any. Which I think is not a really critical issue but at least it should be mentioned in the codex or smth.

If you have anything to add please do!

Answer (score 0):

You can unset this field like that :

```
function wpse_109744_comment_form_fields($fields) {
 if(isset($fields['url']))
  unset($fields['url']);
}
$fields ['email'] = 'your markup';
$fields ['author'] = 'your markup';

$return $fields;
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', 'wpse_109744_comment_form_fields')
```

**EDIT :**

Comment: Thanks ... but the problem is the Wordpress stops accepting comments from the form this is the main issue.

Comment: I've edited my answer. It's better to use hook such as `comment_form_default_fields`

Comment: I'm sorry to say this but I still have **ERROR:** _please fill the required fields (name, email)._

Comment: There's some additional javascript ?

Comment: I've tried to ajaxify the comments but for the sake of test I turned it off so now it's pure POST requests. The thing is when I comment with logged in user (admin) comments are sent and processed as they supposed to be, but when I try to comment as not logged user (name and email are required) it generates this annoying error. I've noticed that the problem appears when I try to change $fields in anyway. When $fields is left unchanged the comment is processed as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I found it finally. you should keep the same name field in both input and textarea.

Example: name="author" & name="email".